# Convert HTML to RTF (HTML2RTF converter)

Tags: php, html, linux, rtf

I'm looking for a simple HTML2RTF converter that I can use on my website which is using a *nix like Operating System. I haven't found anything on the internet, and was hoping the SO community would help me.

PS: I don't want to implement this from scratch, and it doesn't really matter what language it's in, as long as I can run it on a *nix like system. If you guys have already some personalized implementation, the language preferred would be PHP.

Comment: Would OpenOffice on the command line be an option?

Comment: Ugh, I don't really know how OpenOffice works, would I need to install their entire suite just for the converter? Or can I download things separately?

Comment: Also I should mention, the server doesn't have X.

Comment: I think you would have to install the entire suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use the following PERL module.

http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormatRTF

Quick and about 10 lines of code :)

Answer (score 2):

If OpenOffice on the command line is an option, check out [this Forum entry](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=7242) with a great number of starting points. There are certainly stand-alone tools as well, but OpenOffice has quite good rendering capabilities and I'm quite sure it will successfully convert a lot that other converters won't (bulleted / numbered lists, for example).

Answer (score 0):

[Zopyx.convert](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zopyx.convert2/2.1.0) is based on the high-quality BeautifulSoup html parser.  It needs Java & Jython.

If the Java dependency is too much, you should be able to use BeautifulSoup to iterate over the HTMl and build up the output using the [PyRTF](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyRTF/0.45) RTF generator.  Not a five-minute task!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider combining gnuhtml2latex and latex2rtf