# Looking for quality, desktop, cross-platform HTML to RTF solutions

Tags: html, cross-platform, rtf

I'm currently writing a simple cross-platform application (using RealStudio).  I need a cross-platform desktop solution for the conversion of HTML (but preferably HTML+CSS) documents to RTF.  I have seen several posts including (but not limited to) the following:

[HTML+CSS to RTF (in PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605936/htmlcss-to-rtf-in-php)

[Convert HTML to RTF (HTML2RTF converter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110642/convert-html-to-rtf-html2rtf-converter)

[Convert HTML with scripts to RTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301077/convert-html-with-scripts-to-rtf)

The most comprehensive solution seems to be to make use of OpenOffice in headless mode in order to perform conversions.  The only problems are:

- I can't presume upon the presence of OOo and
- I can't afford to have the user to install a full OOo package simply to perform this task.

Therefore, my question in this particular regard is:  Is there any way to only distribute/install the smaller "conversion" portions of OOo for use in headless mode?

My general question, of course, is: What are the best ways to handle HTML to RTF conversion locally?

Answer (score -1):

You can try and simply use textedit on your mac

Comment: The solution I need is not the whole of the application.  It is a portion of the application for integration.